# Making animateLayoutChanges and scroll views play nicely

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an activity that involves form validation, with validation errors appearing below the form fields. The form sometimes discloses additional form fields, and is also long enough that with small screens, it needs to be scrolled if the user should see the bottom. I've animated these transitions using `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` in the layout element. I have the following two related problems with this view:

1. I want to scroll to the very bottom of the scroll view, while an animation (disclosing a form field) is changing the height of the view. If I try to do this, the scrolling stops at the *old* bottom of the view.
2. If the view is already scrolled all the way to the bottom, and an animation occurs that decreases the height of the view--say, a validation error disappearing--then everything stays in the same place until the end of the animation and then snaps up by 10px (or whatever the height decreased by). I want to animate this change.

I feel like there's some trick or API I'm missing--how do I accomplish these?

Thanks!

Comment: does your scrollview child (A layout) has android:animateLayoutChanges ="true" ?

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I know that is asked from long ago but I am stucked with this currently.